# How to program Selenium to bypass Login page?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written 3 Selenium WebDriver 2 tests using Python. All of them log in first and then check functionality further down the application. How could I bypass the login page and go directly to a page?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the @BeforeSuite method to store the login cookie, then your tests can reuse that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application. If it does not allow an unauthorized access to a page, then you have to login.

However, you could possibly pass the authorization once and then access various pages within one session. Just remove steps implying logging out or closing the browser.

If you are using TestNG or JUnit, you can place the authorization to `@BeforeClass` or other `@Before*` method. Which one are you using?

**UPD:**

In case you are using Python+unittest, put authorization actions to the [setUpClass()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) or [startTestRun()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.startTestRun) method, whichever suits better.

Comment: I am using Python unittest with Nose to run the suite.

Comment: @Chakra, I do not work with Python, but I have updated my answer with unittest methods that can be used to place there authorization steps and avoid passing authorization before each test.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a way for a client (selenium test) to bypass the login required by the server?

If it is possible, your security is a big failure.

Selenium has a simple purpose: make a real functionnal test.
If the use must login to do something, test it correctly. So login.